# MFC LoadStringW Is not not loading Japanese string properly from the string table

Tags: c++, windows, string, unicode, mfc

In my MFC application, character set is set to "Multi-byte", I am trying to load a Japanese string stored in string table using LoadStringW function to load the string from the string table but it always reads junk characters.

Do you see any problem in my approach?

I don't want to change character set to Unicode.

One more interesting thing is, I created another sample application and pasted one of the Japanese string from main project to new sample application's string table then tried to load Japanese string with LoadStringW then it works (character set is Multibyte for sample application.)

```
WCHAR wBuf[1024];
int rc;

// load the string from resource file into a wide character array.
rc = LoadStringW(hInstance,iResourceID, wBuf, 1024);
```

Comment: Strings resources are always stored in UNICODE, so I don't think the character set project setting is the culprit here. Can you update your question with the code that calls `LoadStringW()`?

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. It looks fine, but did you check that `rc` is non-zero after the call?

Comment: Yes 'rc' is non zero after call. One more observation is, Japanese characters in string table view (row views) shows garbage characters but if you open same file in notepad++ then it shows correct Japanese strings.

Comment: Ah, so the characters are already corrupted in the string table, which explains why `LoadStringW()` appears to fail (garbage in, garbage out). I would go out on a limb and say someone or something stored multibyte-encoded (probably Shift JIS or EUC-JP) japanese characters directly into the string table. You might want to copy-paste the correct values from Notepad++ into the resource view to "fix" the problem.

Comment: I will try the steps and let you know the findings.

Comment: It happens by mixing multiple languages in a RC file and not saving the file with proper encoding, better have resource only dlls to manage multi-lingual application. [link]http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you save the resource file utf-16 format, not ANSI.
Visual Studio can handle those files just fine.

To save it like that, open the file in Visual Studio as text. Then in the file menu, choose `Advanced Save Options` and then in the dialog specify `Unicode - Codepage 1200`.

Then save the file again.

After that, your resource strings will work as expected.

Comment: +1. Japanese strings are correctly visible in String Table editor and in the normal text files. Need to work on WideCharToMultiByte as it's converting Japanese characters in characters like '???'

Comment: according to MSDN, 1200 is only a valid code page in managed .Net